# UIViewController respondsToSelector: message sent ot deallocated instance

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am posting here after reading some similar threads, but you know each issue still has his own specific problem, that's why I still need your help.

My app crashes with this stack trace:

```
[ReviewVC respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I tracked that on instruments trying to see the relevant code causing the crash:
[image]
[image]
[image]

here is the relevant code for ReviewVC in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method:

```
self.reviewVC = [[[ReviewVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"Review"
                                                     bundle:nil] autorelease];
[viewControllerArray addObject:self.reviewVC];
self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.reviewVC;
```

---

`reviewVC`  is an instance variable and a property, here is it's property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)  ReviewVC *reviewVC;
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do you have a @synthesize? What if you omitted the autorelease?

Comment: yes it's `@synthesize`'d

Comment: Does self.reviewVC ever get set? Set a breakpoint and see what your ReviewVC alloc returns.  Maybe try and retrieve it using [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:] instead.

Comment: I tried to remove the `autorelease` command and all work fine now, still need some explanation about that if possible :)

Comment: What is the purpose of viewControllerArray? You're adding reviewVC and then what? The runtime may have detected that you're not using anymore (assigning the delegate doesn't count). I assume that the reviewVC was gone after that method.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this. It seems maybe `viewControllerArray` is being released and with it the instance `ReviewVC` added to it. I think the autorelease is fine but check how `viewControllerArray` is retained.

```
NSObject obj1;
obj1=[[NSObject alloc] init];
//obj1's retain count is 1 here.

[array1 addobject:obj1];
//obj1's retain count incremented by 1, so the total retain count is 2.

[obj1 release];
//obj1's retain count decremented by 1, so the total retain count is 1.
```